# Why did Jesus ask some recipients of miracles to report to the priests and some he told to speak to no one?

Tags: jesus, gospels, miracle, healing

Jesus performed many miracles while on earth. We see that in some cases the healed person is told to keep the matter private (e.g. Mark 1:44, Matt 9:30); but in other cases the person is told to report to the priests (e.g. Luke 17:13) or tell others (e.g. Mark 5:19).  Why the difference?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Please take the tour - link below.  For a question to be valid, it will need some Bible references.

Comment: The Mosaic Law required them to have a priest declare that they were clean/no leprosy.  This did not require them telling that Jesus healed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus was rather cautious about performing miracles, especially later in His ministry because it aroused much controversy that caused the authorities to turn against Him.  For example:

- The raising of Lazarus (John 11:1-45) galvanised the priests to rapidly advance their plans to have Jesus executed
- Healing the man born blind (John 9:1-41) had a similar effect
- Feeding the 5000 people (Mark 6:30-44) created such a public interest that they wanted to make Jesus king on the spot without recognising Him as a spiritual Messiah!
- The paralytic lowered through the roof (Mark 2:1-12) created much hatred among the priests so that wanted Jesus out of the way.

Thus, Jesus had to limit His publicity so that He could complete His ministry without too much interference from the people and authorities.  Jesus' miracles has some both positive (on the righteous) and negative effects (on the unwilling authorities) on his reputation.  See Mark 1:45.  There were some important exceptions to this:

- In the case of the 10 lepers (Luke 17:11-19) Jesus told them to go and report to the priests because that was what the law required for such healings (Lev 14).
- In the case of the demoniac of Gadara, the area was distinct from Judea and publicity there would little affect Jesus' reputation at Jerusalem.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @Mac's Musings. Jesus understood the forces against his Ministry, he kept his sense of purpose as the Spiritual Messiah, he was not overwhelmed by his fame, Jesus also acknowledges principles/laws of the area which he operates. I asked the question in other to have clarity about how the principles apply to my daily life as his followers. I appreciate your time . Stay blessed

Comment: @Babatunde  Since you are new you may not realize that you can vote up the answer if it is useful and if it answers your question you would want to mark it as the answer by clicking the checkbox. For more information please take the site tour: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour  Welcome to the site.